# Huge memory leak using Entity Framework and Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, castle-windsor

We are experiencing a huge memory leak with our ASP .NET application. It uses EF 6 and Castle Windsor. After the application has been running for several hours, we can easily see that the physical memory steadily climbs with no end in sight. An application restart is our only savior before the application starts timing out.

As you can see from the image below, the memory is taken up by the custom DB context.

[The screenshot shows the memory usage by the custom DB Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsN61.png)

[image]

I think the issue is with the registration of the controller. Everything in the IoC is registered as LifestylePerWebRequest except for the controller which is registered as LifestyleTransient. If I try to register the controller as LifestylePerWebRequest, I get an error like the one below. I think the container is holding on to all of these instances and not knowing when to let them go.

A single instance of controller 'Acme.Web.Controllers.HomeController' cannot be used to handle multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.

How can I resolve this so that the DB Context is cleaned up along with the rest of the hierarchy?

Comment: Maybe this post from "Mr DI" helps:http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/

Comment: Thanks but that looks like it's for Web API only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory Leaks when using Entity Framework and Windsor in an ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226113/memory-leaks-when-using-entity-framework-and-windsor-in-an-asp-net-mvc-applicati)

Comment: See also [Castle Windsor: Avoid memory leaks by learning the underlying mechanics](http://tommarien.github.io/blog/2012/04/21/castle-windsor-avoid-memory-leaks-by-learning-the-underlying-mechanics). This appears to be a well documented issue as there are many results when you Google `"castle windsor memory leak asp.net mvc"`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the answer. I had come across the WindsorControllerFactory before but I didn't put it to use. Now that it's in place and registered as shown below, the container is releasing the controller. Now that it's being released it get picked up for garbage collection. It seems to be working really well so far.

```
var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could do:

```
_container.Kernel.ReleasePolicy = new NoTrackingReleasePolicy();
```

I think a better approach, unless you use the same context throughout all your layers, is to IoC inject a DbContextFactory and in the repository, you'd create a using statement around the Create() call on the factory.  Then you can kill dbcontext when you are done and not let the container deal with that.  You could even let the factory hang on to the first context, if you really needed to and on dispose of dbcontextfactory, you can call dispose on the internal dbcontext.